# Problem with the historical exchange rate of the JPY in R

Tags: r

I was downloading historical data using the `priceR` package with the `historical_exchange_rates` function, but I am experiencing problems with the Yen. I have downloaded 10 other currencies and no problem, but the Yen/USD exchange rate is wrong, and it is the same as the Euro/USD. Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is a typo - `LPY` not `JPY`. If the from or to parameters are a string it does not recognise it seems to default to euro and US. I cannot be sure though as the documentation doesn't state these defaults and the function provides no warnings or errors regarding the issue (which it really should).

For example, these both return the same values:

```
historical_exchange_rates(from="EUR", to="USD", start_date = "2006-01-01", end_date = "2006-01-05")
historical_exchange_rates(from="", to="", start_date = "2006-01-01", end_date = "2006-01-05")
```